# Profiling shows most of the time is spend in Hibernate loading classes - how to fix this?

Tags: hibernate, java-8, classloader

We are profiling performance problems in a large JBoss/Hib application. Profiling shows that most time is spent in the following code:

```
QueryTranslaterImpl.compile(Map, boolean)
- ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(String)
  - ClassLoader.findLoadedClass0(String)
```

Essentially, the whole request takes 8.5 seconds. Of these, 7.8s are spent in these fragments inside Hibernate. Each call to loadClass takes pretty consistently either 298ms or 149ms, and there are many such attempts to load a class.

Any ideas what we could do to improve/fix this performance issue?

Comment: not a bad question, but probably opening a hibernate issue in their JIRA would get you more info

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem with the Hibernate Criteria framework. 
In this [blog post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-performance-penalty-of-class-forname-when-parsing-jpql-and-criteria-queries/#more-6674) and related [Jira Issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-4959), the solution is presented.

Unfortunately, this is only fixed in Hibernate 5.2.6.

The Hibernate we use is included from a third-party framework that won't perform an major version upgrade anytime soon.

So I will leave this answer here, but not accept it, as any answer that could solve or improve our problem using Hibernate 4.x is very welcome.